# React Native onPressOut

Tags: react-native, gesture, drag, onpress

I am using `react-native`. I want to trigger the function when the user releases the screen. However, `onPressOut` fires even if the user drags the finger.
Is there any simple way that I can detect the timing when the user releases their finger?

```
 onPressIn={() => {
        console.warn('Pressed!');
      }}
      onPressOut={() => {
        console.warn('Released');
      }}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for touchend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchend_event

Comment: @EmilKarlsson I think that's web specific, he's asking about `react-native`. correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onPressOut` will be called the moment you drag something even if the user still touching the screen.

You should check `onPanResponderRelease`, it will trigger when the user releases the touch after dragging. Documentation [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder)